# How to get request status of SOAP web service one way method in .NET C#?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, http-response-codes

I am consuming SOAP web services (by adding Service Reference to the wsdl).

But for the one-way operations (void methods/don't have output). How can I know the status of the request? How can I read the response status code if it is 200 OK or something else? Any idea how can I achieve that in C# .NET ?

Comment: What kind of .NET are you using? And please provide the code example of your try.

Comment: It is not a .NET application. I am using Outsystems low code platform and trying to consume the soap web service through .NET extensions, so I only calling the .NET c# method that consumes soap web service (through the .NET Web Service Reference) and I am passing the inputs from the Outsystems platform. It is working fine, but we need to get the request status and log it instead of fire and forget. I will try to write a similar code to mine since our company does not allow sharing codes publicly, and I will post it tomorrow.